# Sample executing an azure cosmos db stored procedure in powershell

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have deployed an *stored proc* on azure **cosmos** db but dont know how to execute it through **powershell**. Does anyone have an example?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Cosmos DB PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/?view=azps-6.3.0) documentation, it looks like you can only manage Stored Procedures (Create, Delete etc.) but not execute it.

Cosmos DB does have a REST API that you can use to execute Stored Procedures. So using powershell, you could do the following:

```
$url = "https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/sprocs/{sproc-name}"


Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url
```

The documentation for executing a Stored Procedure in Cosmos via REST can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/execute-a-stored-procedure).